# Javascript & Regex, multiples matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I have a quick question for you (for you, I've personally spent hours on this). I've created a web application in Javascript/Jquery to validate a CSS stylesheet.

I need to extract multiple CSS class names from a selector with Regex. I've done something like:

```
var selector = this.value;
var userNewClass = selector.match(/[.]([A-Za-z_-]*)/);
alert(userNewClass.toString());
```

It's almost working, but I have two issues with the code (you have a Regex noob here).
If I write something like:

```
.test:hover
```

It returns me

```
.test, test
```

The same class name but on with the dot and the other without the dot. 
If I write a selector with multiple class name:

```
.test, .hello
```

I'm getting the same result...Is there anyway to modify my Regex (or my code ?) to obtain all the classes names with the dot (.) only, considering the user can have a unlimited number of classes in the same selector?

Comment: I think you should just move the `dot` inside the capture group: - `/([.][A-Za-z_-]*)/`

Comment: What if I'd added a rule set for `body.about` or `.button.disabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.test` is the full match, `test` is the captured group (anything in parens `()`). You also need to add a `g` at the end after the closing `/` to match every instance and not just the first one.

That said, you likely don't need regex for this and might be better served using `split` on the string.

```
'.test, .hello'.split(', ') // returns an array ['.test', '.hello']
```

If you absolutely must use regex, try this:

```
/\.(\w+)/g
```

This will match (and capture) any and all sequences of one or more letters and/or numbers `\w+` which follow a literal `.`

Comment: For more details about the resulting array of matches, check out the table for [`RegExp.exec()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description) (It's the same structure as returned by `String.match()`) Also, if you want to individually handle the captured groups for all matches, you need to use `RegExp.exec()` in some sort of loop: `while((m = re.exec(s)) !== null) { /* inspect m */ }`.

Comment: Great ! Actually, I need Regex because the selector, as @popnoodles said, can be `em.test:hover, em.hello:first-letter`. Sorry I wasn't clear on this point. The "g" solution works perfectly ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the RegExp.exec method:

```
var input = ".test1.test2 .test3, .test4";

var re = /\.[\w\-]+/ig, match, matches = [];

while (match = re.exec(input)) {
  matches.push(match[0]);
}

alert(matches);
```

Using split will not work, as you will have to parse out pseudo classes and all other possible CSS syntax elements.